# Autocomplete don't give result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have problem with autocomplete script. Script don't give any names under input.
Here is index:

```
<head>
        <html lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>

      function getData(){
      var userName = document.getElementById("tags");
      var string = userName.value;
         $.ajax({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'bla.php',
                  data: {
                    str: string
                  },
                  success: function(content) {
                    console.log("Content: " + content);

         var availableTags = content;
       function split( val ) {
          return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                  }
               });


      } 
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Names: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50" onKeyDown="getData();">
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is bla.php
Connect to db is correct, data from Db is correct.

```
    $d = new Database();
$d->query("SELECT u.cele_jmeno, u.id FROM uzivatele u WHERE u.cele_jmeno LIKE CONCAT(:str,'%') ORDER BY u.cele_jmeno LIMIT 0,15");   
 $d->bind(":str", $_POST["str"]);
 $vysledky = $d->resultset();
 $res = Array();
 $num = 0;
 foreach($vysledky AS $vysledek){
    $res[$num] = $vysledek["cele_jmeno"];
    $num++;

 }  
    echo  json_encode($res);
```

In ajax I have console log, which return coorect values. For example If I inser into input Ter, then in console.log i Have: Content:  ["Terrence Rowell","Terry Moony","Terry Morco"] and if I insert Terry i have only Content:  ["Terry Moony","Terry Morco"]. It's all correct data, but, script nothing write into autocomplete box. When, I have data in array in javascrit, all works, but if I insert array from php script i have no autocomplete box.

Here is screenshot:
[Box when I write first letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpkvI.png)

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Please fix your posts spelling please to make it easier for users.

Comment: I don't have any errors in console.

Comment: Load your jQuery below the DOM or wrap in in the `DOMContentLoaded`/`document.ready`, see if that helps.

Comment: Move all your js into inside the document ready `$(document).ready(function(){  //move everything to here });`

Comment: Are you sure that in the "source: function..." you still have valid value in availableTags ?

Comment: which php version you are using?

Comment: I have php 7.0.17

Answer (score 0):

Because you return a json encode value so split function work as letter by letter instead one string...So need to give dataType as json.

Add data type into your ajax request for ex:
`dataType: "json",` like this

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: 'bla.php',
dataType: "json",
data: {
      str: string
}, etc...
```

My test1.php

```
<head>
        <html lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>

      function getData(){
      var userName = document.getElementById("tags");
      var string = userName.value;
         $.ajax({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'test.php',
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {
                    str: string
                  },
                  success: function(content) {
                    console.log("Content: " + content);

         var availableTags = content;
       function split( val ) {
          return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                  }
               });


      } 
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Names: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50" onKeyDown="getData();">
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

and my test.php

```
<?php 
$vysledky = ["Terry Moony","Terry Morco","window","Libertéz"];
$num = 0;
foreach($vysledky AS $vysledek){
    //print_r($vysledek);
    $res[$num] = $vysledek;
    $num++;

 }  

echo  json_encode($res);

?>
```

Comment: With dataType json ajax return error message: parserror.

Comment: The reason why this `parserror` message occurs is that when you simply return a string or another value, it is not really `Json`, so the parser fails when parsing it

Comment: It's name from database Thalia Libertéz.

Comment: I have parsererror when i add dataType to ajax, i know why, but how to send data from that php script to javascript if json_encode can't create json which ajax need?

Comment: when i try with your code it works fine when i add dataType as Json

Comment: Ok, can you see my code on this page:
http://www.alohomora.cz/system/admin/odznaky/pokus.php
Maybe it's will be helpfull.

Comment: your output data is an array so that's why you get an parse error

Comment: I used your test file, and i have error. Again parsererror.

Answer (score 0):

check your php version, and use snippets accordingly,

```
if php version>=5.4
<?php 
$vysledky = ["Terry Moony","Terry Morco","window","Libertéz"];
$num = 0;
foreach($vysledky AS $vysledek){
    $res[$num] = $vysledek;
    $num++;
}  
echo  json_encode($res,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>

Before PHP 5.4, you can use this snippet:

<?php 
$vysledky = ["Terry Moony","Terry Morco","window","Libertéz"];
$num = 0;
foreach($vysledky AS $vysledek){
    $res[$num] = $vysledek;
    $num++;
}  
$holder =   json_encode($res);
$holder = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', function($matches) {return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $matches[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');}, $holder);

?>
```